# Webapi with MVP based webform application

Tags: webforms, asp.net-web-api, mvp

We have a web application built using ASP .NET 4.5 Webforms stack and based on MVP Pattern.
We are currently in the process of making certain aspects of the application service-oriented 
which can then be used to serve the relevant content to third party clients.

Rather than doing a major overhaul, one of the options we are looking out is exposing this as WebAPI endpoints. Is anyone aware of codeplex/github hosted sample projects demonstrating the use of WebAPI ends points with MVP based webforms application? Any suggestions/insight/ recommendations would be helpful? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A sample using Web Forms + Web API can be found here:

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#Samples/WebApi/WebFormSample/ReadMe.txt